# Chrome not autoplaying video

Tags: google-chrome, video, html5-video

I'm using autoplay video sporadically throughout a client's site, however the below code is (for some reason), not autoplaying in Chrome(63.0.3239.132). Works fine in Safari and FF.

I am not getting any console errors either?

```
<video src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/247833422.hd.mp4?s=8d872a36d3dbe7f74e9613ab144d088b5bab6649&profile_id=174" poster="" preload autoplay loop muted></video>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick fix for Chrome:

```
<video src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/247833422.hd.mp4?s=8d872a36d3dbe7f74e9613ab144d088b5bab6649&profile_id=174" id="video1" poster="" preload autoplay loop muted></video>

<script> 
    document.getElementById('video1').play(); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to google chrome's policy  unmuted videos will not auto play or programmatically play. To auto play video just mute your video by add muted attribute like below :

```
<video autoplay loop muted="muted"></video>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to this, set the video to muted `<video autoplay loop muted><source...`

Comment: oh you did... but anyway, it's worth leaving here for others :)